# in app billing subscription wont work after re-installing android app

Tags: android, in-app-billing, subscriptions

Im developing an android app with an in app billing support for subscriptions.
Im trying to find it hard to understand a use case that a user subscribes and after that removes the app and later installs it again. 
Will the app automatically recognize that the user(Same google play user) has already subscribed?

I read the documentation and in some places it seems like it is supposed to work and some not.
For example from the page [Implementing subscriptions](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/v2/billing_subscriptions.html) :

> After receiving a purchase token, your apps can store the token locally or pass it to your backend servers, which can then use it to query the billing status or cancel the subscription remotely. If your app will store the token locally, please read the Security and Design document for best practices for maintaining the security of your data.

From this quote I can understand that the token is saved locally or on a server. In my case I don't have a server so it is saved locally and I can suppose that after removing the app the user wont be able to reuse the token with another installation of the same app.

But in other places it shows that Subscriptions work on asynchronous method and will create a request to google play servers and check if the user is subscribed.

So I'm a bit confused here...

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: The page you link to is for v2 of the in-app billing API. v3 is the newest and has (as far as I can tell) has support for checking and restoring user purchases. Are you perhaps getting confused and reading pages for both versions?

Comment: Hi, From my understanding V3 does not support subscription currently

Comment: Your understanding is incorrect. At least, according to the v3 documentation.